# While installing Magento 2 on Ubuntu LTS 16.04, i am getting some different error

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, magento2.2

I have already installed these packages.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php-mysql php-dom \
php-simplexml php-curl php-intl php-xsl php-mbstring php-zip php-xml composer
```

After this command

```
composer install
```

I am getting this error

```
Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 but your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - The requested PHP extension ext-bcmath * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's bcmath extension.
  Problem 3
    - The requested PHP extension ext-soap * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for magento/composer 1.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/composer[1.4.0].
    - magento/composer 1.4.0 requires php ~7.1.3|~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.7.3 -> satisfiable by php-amqplib/php-amqplib[v2.7.3].
    - php-amqplib/php-amqplib v2.7.3 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for symfony/console v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/console v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - Installation request for symfony/filesystem v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/filesystem[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/filesystem v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - Installation request for symfony/finder v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/finder v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - Installation request for symfony/process v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/process v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-code 3.3.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-code[3.3.1].
    - zendframework/zend-code 3.3.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 12
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
  Problem 13
    - Installation request for doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.6.0].
    - doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 14
    - Installation request for doctrine/collections v1.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/collections[v1.5.0].
    - doctrine/collections v1.5.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 15
    - Installation request for doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 16
    - Installation request for moontoast/math 1.1.2 -> satisfiable by moontoast/math[1.1.2].
    - moontoast/math 1.1.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
  Problem 17
    - Installation request for myclabs/deep-copy 1.8.1 -> satisfiable by myclabs/deep-copy[1.8.1].
    - myclabs/deep-copy 1.8.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 18
    - Installation request for symfony/browser-kit v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/browser-kit[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/browser-kit v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 19
    - Installation request for symfony/config v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/config[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/config v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 20
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/css-selector v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 21
    - Installation request for symfony/dependency-injection v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/dependency-injection[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/dependency-injection v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 22
    - Installation request for symfony/dom-crawler v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/dom-crawler[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/dom-crawler v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 23
    - Installation request for symfony/http-foundation v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/http-foundation v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 24
    - Installation request for symfony/options-resolver v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/options-resolver[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/options-resolver v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 25
    - Installation request for symfony/stopwatch v4.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/stopwatch[v4.1.6].
    - symfony/stopwatch v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 26
    - symfony/console v4.1.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - sebastian/phpcpd 3.0.1 requires symfony/console ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.1.6].
    - Installation request for sebastian/phpcpd 3.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[3.0.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:

- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Answer (score 3):

**step1:**  first better to remove the php from your ubuntu using this command.
 it will only remove php and its modules

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

**step2:** PHP 7.1 isn’t available on Ubuntu default repositories… in order to install it,
 you will have to get it from third-party repositories.
Run the commands below to add the below third party repository to install PHP 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

**step:3**
now install the required modules.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-common php7.1-mbstring   php7.1-xmlrpc php7.1-soap php7.1-gd php7.1-xml php7.1-intl php7.1-mysql php7.1-cli php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-zip php7.1-curl composer
```

Comment: Thank you @spider01

Comment: this worked to install my required php version and then run composer. However, now my apache isn't serving php anymore. (I'm guessing step1 is to blame?)

Comment: @user1073075 You'll need to restart Apache to reload the PHP module with the new configuration. The command line PHP starts a new PHP instance each time with the latest configuration, whereas the PHP extension running in Apache is separate, and only loads new configuration setting when Apache itself is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, using this command error is resolved
    **sudo apt-get install php-bcmath php-soap**